# Grep variable pattern match

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

How can I get this to work?

```
#!/bin/bash
SOMETHING=$(egrep '^  something' /some/dir/file.conf | awk -F '.' '{print $1}' | awk    '{print $2}')

if [ $SOMETHING = 123 ]; then
    echo "Found 123"
    else
    echo "Cannot find 123" && exit 1
fi
```

Results in grep complaining about a syntax error.  It doesn't like the '^  something'

Comment: What do you want it to match, exactly?

Comment: edit your question with examples please. `grep|awk|cut` should not the best way to go.

Comment: mv `SOMETHING=$(egrep '^  something' somefile.conf | awk '{print $4}' | cut -c1-3)` above the test, and then just put `$SOMETHING` in the test.

Comment: [UUO-G](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your multiple commands with pipes can be simply replaced with the awk itself. Use following script:

```
SOMETHING=$(awk '/^ something/{print substr($4, 1, 3);}' somefile.conf)
if [ "$SOMETHING" = "123" ]; then
    echo "Found 123"
else
    echo "Cannot find 123" && exit 1  
fi
```

**EDIT:** Looks like you've edited the question and your script after I posted my anser. Here is the modified awk command for you latest edit (don't do it again pls):

```
SOMETHING=$(awk -F "." '/^ something/{split($1, a, " "); print a[2]}' somefile.conf)
```